# git squash all scattered commits by author into a single commit

Tags: git, github

I was recently contributing to a repo for first time, and during that I often committed for each milestone, now I want to deliver it in single clean commit.

The commits are not consecutive continuous, it is scattered between commits from different other committers.So doing soft reset wouldn't work here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if they moving them all into one commit would cause conflicts with other changes that have happened since?

Comment: yeah it will have conflicts, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: As an aside, you should never wind up in this state. The problem you're facing now, having your commits mixed with other people, should have been avoided in the first place by working on a branch. You're free to commit as often as you'd like, but you should be committing to a branch that you can periodically rebase against original branch where other people are committing. When you're done, it's a very simple one-line command to squash all of your commits into one commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have pointed, probably you are going to find a lot of nasty conflitcs, but in case you want to proceed this is what I would do:

Create a branch and cherry-pick one by one all the commits you want, then merge into master using --squash.

Comment: this definitely helped me, and now I have single clean commit, ready for pull request, thanks Antonio MG